# Shares endpoint on LinkedIn API not working

Tags: api, linkedin-api

The endpoint to get shares by owner is not working for me.
This is the full URL I'm using:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:{ID}
```

But I receive this error:

```
{"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"Invalid query parameters passed to request","status":400}
```

I know the access token I'm using is working, if I try to get one share by ID the response is a success, using the following URL:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares/urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A{ID}
```

Am I doing something wrong? For me this error looks like a bug in the API

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're having trouble with the shares by owner endpoint on LinkedIn's API. Here's the correct URL format to use:

```py
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:{ID}&sortBy=CREATED&sharesPerOwner=1000&count=100&start=0
```

Please replace `{ID}` with your org ID. I included the additional parameters.

NOTE: I tested the url. It works.